# Thin Disk Potential-Density Relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential, galaxies

Suppose that there is an infinitesimally thin disk in the plane $z=0$ with surface density $\Sigma(x,y)$. How do you show that the potential $\phi(x,y)$ in the disk satisfies

$$\Sigma(x',y') = \frac{1}{4\pi^2G}\int\int\frac{dx\,dy}{|\bf{x}-\bf{x'}|}\big(\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}\big)$$

I have attempted this question using Fourier transform and couldn't make much progress. I think it can be solved by different transform methods (e.g. Mellin transform, Laplace transform, etc).

Comment: Isn't a case where you simply need to use $-\nabla^2\phi =-\rho/\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, so it would be $\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}=4\pi G\Sigma\delta(z)$. But where to go from that I don't know.

Comment: nevermind...  :(

Comment: Could you quickly confirm the integration is over the surface of the disk?  Also what is G?

Comment: Where is this problem coming from? How do you know the formula is correct? Can you give some context or a reference?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero G is just the gravitational constant. I think the integration is over the surface of the disk, although I am not completely sure.

Comment: @octonion I'm working through the Binney & Tremaine book on Galactic Dynamics, it's a problem in Chapter 2 of that book.

Comment: Well assuming it's correct here's a hint maybe. You can consider $\Sigma$ to be $\delta(x')\delta(y')$ and plug in the potential of a point charge into your formula to derive an integral expression for the delta function. Then you can write an arbitrary potential as an integral over point sources, and you'll see your formula is valid as long as it is valid for the delta function. But I was skeptical the formula is valid for the delta function since the integrand seems to be strictly positive.